# PHP changes color in the navbar

Tags: php, html, css

I'm just starting with HTML and PHP and I ran into the following problem:
When having a PHP command the webpage shows wrong colors!
With PHP command (`<?php phpinfo( ); ?>`)
[image: With PHP Command]
Without PHP command:
[image: Without PHP command]
It's pretty clear to see that the navbar elements change color, depending on the command, but why?
I can't get this fixed, no matter what I do. Here's my other code:
PHP-Source-File:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP-Info</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <div style="float: right;">
                <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="">Server-Info</a></li>
                <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar active" href="phpinfo.php">PHP-Info</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <?php phpinfo( ); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
* {
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-top: 55px;
}
ul.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.4%;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
}
li.navbar {
  float: left;
}
li a.navbar {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover.navbar {
    border-bottom: 4px solid dodgerblue;
}
li a.active.navbar {
  background-color: #666666;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #666666;
}
```

Comment: phpinfo() by default has a style, you can see this in page source, for fix this problem you must rewrite that style and set **!important**

Comment: Check the styles in the browser. Seems like the css of the phpinfo is overriding the li-style of the navbar. Even tho i'd say that phpinfo is not meant to run inside a website.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS stylesheet I see you have `:hover` and `:active` before your classes. Try switching them around, like this:

```
li a.navbar:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid DodgerBlue;
}
li a.navbar:active {
  background-color: #666666;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #666666;
}
```

EDIT: Plus you had a period `.` instead of a colon `:` before `active`.
It is also a good idea to capitalize your color names. `DodgerBlue` instead of `dodgerblue`. Some browsers are strict about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it stopped working completely with your code ^^

Comment: @itzFlubby one of your CSS classes is declared `a.active.navbar`. CSS will interpret `active` as a class.

Comment: It is a class :p

Comment: @itzFlubby that is strange to me. I also see your class declared `a:hover.navbar`. Is hover supposed to be a class? If not then switch it around to `a.navbar:hover`.